# Google Places "Address" type restriction does not properly filter precise addresses

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to implement Google Places Autocomplete, but whenever I add the type restriction of "address", it still allows full streets to be selected.

The documentation states:

> address instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results with a precise address. Generally, you use this request when you know the user will be looking for a fully specified address.

I'm not experiencing this though. If you start to enter input without a street number into the autocomplete field, it will suggest non-precise locations (e.g. Mount Misery Road, Melville, NY, USA).

We're looking to use this to enter addresses for e-commerce related purposes, is there a way to force Google to only return **precise** addressess? The documentation states it should be possible, but I'm not experiencing correct behavior.

My API key does not allow for direct API access, but I presume this link will reproduce similar results. My development environment is locked down so I'm unable to link to the implementation, but the initialization code is included below.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Mount%20Misery&types=address&key=AIzaSyDI6gf-Rvf1xEpm7sSoJyiL7gIB9Mulj48

```js
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($input[0], {
                types: ['address'],
                componentRestrictions: {
                    country: $form.find('select[name*=country]').val()
                }
            });
```

Comment: Having this exact same issue... did you every figure anything out?